# SugarCRM package navigation issue

Tags: sugarcrm

I have created a package in sugar 7.2.0.0. I have installed it on sugar 7.5.0.0. It is working fine over there.
But when I install it in sugar 7.7.0.0 the package's navigation is pointing to some different URL's.

In Sugar 7.5 menu is pointing to a URL like:

```
http://localhost/SugarPro7/#bwc/index.php?module=module_name&action=action_name
```

In sugar 7.7 menu is is pointing to a URL like:

```
http://localhost/SugarPro7/#module_name/action_name
```

When in sugar 7.7, I manually type URL like that of sugar 7.5 it works fine.

I want the navigation to point at the same location on both versions.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: for those who have similar problem, I have found the solution on SugarCRM community forum. Link to the post is: https://community.sugarcrm.com/message/81030#comment-81030